# Right Column of Windows 7 Start Menu is transparent across all themes?

Tags: windows-7, themes, start-menu, transparency

I've had this problem for awhile now, and I don't know how I did it.

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

As you can see, the right column is transparent, and it shows as this across all my regular and downloaded themes. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: You used the program Nimi Visuals? if so undo the changes by him.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed something that's doing it, as that's looks like a Start Menu/Explorer enhancer/replacement.

Go though your Add/Remove programs, and/or use MSConfig to find the program that causing it.

You could also perform a System Restore back to before it started behaving this way.